# Algolia datacenter for graph.cool

Tags: algolia

I want to use Algolia with graph.cool. Which region should I choose, when I create new app in Algolia?? If I am not wrong, graph.cool backend located in Dublin...Europe(DE) or Europe(FR) or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily have an idea of the latency between AWS Dublin and Algolia's regions by looking at their status website:

- Here is the monitoring for a **Europe (FR)** cluster of machines: https://status.algolia.com/clusters/c4-fr
- Here is the monitoring for a **Europe (DE)** cluster of machines: https://status.algolia.com/clusters/c1-de

*tldr;* **FR** is 16ms away, **DE** is 25ms.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have no idea about this sites.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the Graphcool backend is hosted in Ireland, eu-west-1. (I asked on their [community slack](https://slack.graph.cool/).)

When you choose the region for your Algolia app, the most important thing to consider is where your users are going to be. The latency of the API calls from their browser/device to Algolia is the most important thing to reduce, so the search feels super fast.

If your users will be mostly in the EU, than Europe (DE) and Europe (FR) are good choices. If users will be split between the US and the EU, you might consider US-East.